# CFOAUTH in CF2021 - Can't get the result because of the redirecturi

Tags: oauth, coldfusion

I'm using CFOAuth to call a custom authentication created by another team. It works but the problem is I can't retrieve the result because of the redirect. I know it gets back to the redirecturi page because I stop it there but the result does not exists. How do I get the result?

```
<cfoauth 
   clientid="client.userprofile" 
   scope="app.client.userprofile"
   authendpoint="https://www.authorization-location.com/connect/authorize" 
   accesstokenendpoint="https://www.authorization-location.com/connect/token"
   result="authResult" 
   redirecturi="https://www.my-location.com/appname/index.cfm"
   urlparams="code_challenge=abcxyz&code_challenge_method=S256&response_type=code" />
```

I tried referencing the result after the cfoauth call but it never gets to that part of the code because if it's successful, it redirects to the new page. I tried referencing the result from the new page but it doesn't exists when it gets there.